# How do I stop programs from closing when I right click them on the taskbar?

Tags: ubuntu-mate, panel, taskbar, mate-panel

I'm using a laptop, and I keep accidentally right clicking on programs in the taskbar. As it's currently set up, when I right click an item on the taskbar, it closes that program. How do I change it so that right clicking a program does not close it?

I am using Ubuntu MATE version 20.04.

Comment: What is the output of `gsettings get org.mate.panel default-layout`? Which dock do you use?

Comment: `'redmond--test-tweak'`. I think I'm using mate-panel - the default that came with ubuntu-mate.